# protoファイルのメッセージ型の中に記述する、フィールド型の指定する型がわからない

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

protoファイルを作成し、Go、Nuxtでマイクロサービスを作成し、通信をgRPCで行うサービスを開発しております。

ある機能を実現させるため、Youtube Data APIを用いて、取得したデータをフロントサービスにレスポンスとして送ることを考えております。

Youtube Data APIのレスポンスはJSONオブジェクトとして返却されてきますが、その場合に、protoファイルのメッセージ型の中で、フィールドの型をどのように指定すればよいかわからず、長考しております。

```
message ChannelListResponse{
   ＜型＞ channel_list = 1 ;
}
```

アドバイスをいただけると幸いです。

### 追記：やりたいこと

私が行いたい処理として、"google.golang.org/api/youtube/v3"というパッケージをGoで用いて、Youtube Data APIレスポンスを取得し、gRPCで通信してフロントサービスへ返却するという処理です。そのため、protoファイルでメッセージ型の中でYoutube Data APIレスポンスが格納できるフィールドタイプを指定する必要があります。

Goの構造体と同じ扱いができるものをprotoファイルの中で定義できることは、アドバイスをいただき理解ができました。

そして、"google.golang.org/api/youtube/v3"にはYoutube Data APIレスポンスであるJSONオブジェクトからGoの構造体にデコードするため、独自の構造体とメソッドが定義されております。つまり、フロントサービスへ返却するのは、"google.golang.org/api/youtube/v3"で定義されている構造体から生成されたデータとなります。そのため、Youtube Data APIレスポンスをそのままフロントサービスへ返却するには、"google.golang.org/api/youtube/v3"で定義されている構造体と全く同じ構造体を、protoファイルに記述する必要があります。

私が詰まっている点としては、"google.golang.org/api/youtube/v3"で定義されている構造体と全く同じ型定義を、自分で記述する以外に何か良い方法はないのかという点です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go でいう構造体の型のようなものを Protocol Buffers の型として定義できるので、これを使うとよさそうです: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#other

API レスポンスの JSON のスキーマを元に gRPC の型を自動生成することは、やろうと思えばできるとは思いますが、おすすめしません。Protocol Buffers にはデフォルト値の概念があったりと JSON とは意味論が異なる部分があるというのと、得られた API レスポンスのすべてを gRPC で返したい場合はほぼ無いだろうというのが理由です。

使いたい API エンドポイントはそう多くはないでしょうし、自分で書いちゃうのが今の時点では一番早いかと思います。

Comment: GoにはYoutube Data APIを使用するためのパッケージがあり、そのパッケージの中に各APIレスポンスに対応した構造体が定義されています。それらをprotoファイルに定義することはできないということでしょうか？

Comment: Go の構造体とほぼ同じ扱いをできるものが protobuf にもあるので書けるという話をしています。前提となる話がもっと具体的になるよう質問文を編集くださればもっと具体的な回答ができるかもです。

Comment: 状況説明不足で申し訳ありません。 まず私が行いたい処理として、 "google.golang.org/api/youtube/v3"というパッケージをGoで用いて、Youtube Data APIレスポンスを取得し、gRPCで通信してフロントサービスへ返却するという処理です。そのため、protoファイルでメッセージ型の中でYoutube Data APIレスポンスが格納できるフィールドタイプを指定する必要があります。Goの構造体と同じ扱いができるものをprotoファイルの中で定義できることは、アドバイスをいただき理解ができました。(1/3)

Comment: そして、"google.golang.org/api/youtube/v3"にはYoutube Data APIレスポンスであるJSONオブジェクトからGoの構造体にデコードするため、独自の構造体とメソッドが定義されております。つまり、フロントサービスへ返却するは、"google.golang.org/api/youtube/v3"で定義されている構造体から生成されたデータとなります。そのため、Youtube Data APIレスポンスをそのままフロントサービスへ返却するには、"google.golang.org/api/youtube/v3"で定義されている構造体と全く同じ構造体を、protoファイルに記述する必要があります。(2/3)

Comment: 私が詰まっている点としては、"google.golang.org/api/youtube/v3"で定義されている構造体と全く同じ型定義を、自分で記述する以外に何か良い方法はないのかという点です。長文失礼致します。(3/3)

Comment: コメントだと改行できなかったり他の回答を試みる方が見辛かったりするので、内容を質問文に移しました。そして具体的にというのは、具体的なコードと一緒に、どの API エンドポイントのレスポンスを gRPC レスポンスに詰め込むのを悩んでらっしゃるのだろう？、というところでした。そうすると私も具体的なコードで回答できるためです。

Comment: 一例ではあるのですが、https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list?hl=ja←こちらのエンドポイントにpart名はsnippetとしてリクエストを送り、取得したレスポンスをgRPCを使用してフロントサービスへ送りたいと考えております。

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございました。自分で定義する方法が良いということは、理解ができました！ もう一点ご質問なのですが、Youtube Data APIレスポンスとして配列が返却された場合に、やはり自分でAPIレスポンスに対応した構造体と、その構造体が要素の型となるスライスを定義して、for文などで繰り返し代入をしていくしか方法がないのでしょうか？

Comment: 新しい質問は、別の質問として新しく投稿してみてください。